# gtk4 styleprovider vs set_css_classes

Tags: vala, gtk4

What is the current correct way to use css in Gtk 4.12.3 wayland?
Am getting conflicting information about StyleContext, where some docs say its depreciated, while others say its OK for the Display.
I've tried `Gtk.StyleContext.add_provider_for_display()` and `set_css_classes()`, which works but spews heaps of warnings like this:

```
/home/cpb/Desktop/txt/source/valatemp_nil.vala:31.3-31.18: warning: `Gtk.StyleContext' has been deprecated since 4.10
   31 |         Gtk.StyleContext.add_provider_for_display(thisdisplay, allcsp, Gtk.STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_USER);
      |         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~                                                                                 
/home/cpb/Desktop/txt/source/valatemp_nil.vala.c: In function ‘__lambda4_’:
/home/cpb/Desktop/txt/source/valatemp_nil.vala.c:127:61: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘gtk_widget_set_css_classes’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
  127 |         gtk_widget_set_css_classes ((GtkWidget*) container, _tmp10_);
      |                                                             ^~~~~~~
      |                                                             |
      |                                                             gchar ** {aka char **}
In file included from /usr/include/gtk-4.0/gtk/gtkapplication.h:26,
                 from /usr/include/gtk-4.0/gtk/gtkwindow.h:32,
                 from /usr/include/gtk-4.0/gtk/gtkaboutdialog.h:29,
                 from /usr/include/gtk-4.0/gtk/gtk.h:33,
                 from /home/cpb/Desktop/txt/source/valatemp_nil.vala.c:10:
/usr/include/gtk-4.0/gtk/gtkwidget.h:929:71: note: expected ‘const char **’ but argument is of type ‘gchar **’ {aka ‘char **’}
  929 |                                                          const char **classes);
...
```

and a sample application,
css is a string, fed to a CssProvider which is fed to a StyleContext for default display, which is used by set_css_classes per widget:

```
using Gtk;
int main (string[] args) {
    Gtk.Application wut = new Gtk.Application ("com.test.test", GLib.ApplicationFlags.DEFAULT_FLAGS);
    wut.activate.connect(() => {

        Gtk.ApplicationWindow win = new Gtk.ApplicationWindow(wut);
        Gtk.Box container = new Gtk.Box(VERTICAL,0);
        Gtk.Box socket = new Gtk.Box(HORIZONTAL,0);
        Gtk.ToggleButton btn = new Gtk.ToggleButton();

        string csses = """
            .rr {
                background:                 #FF5555; 
            }
            .bb { 
                background:                 #5555FF; 
            }
            .gg {
                background:                 #55ff55; 
            }
        """;

        Gtk.CssProvider allcsp = new Gtk.CssProvider();
        allcsp.load_from_string(csses);
        Gdk.Display thisdisplay = Gdk.Display.get_default();
        Gtk.StyleContext.add_provider_for_display(thisdisplay, allcsp, Gtk.STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_USER);

        container.set_css_classes({"bb"});
        socket.set_css_classes({"gg"});
        btn.set_css_classes({"rr"});

        socket.append(btn);
        container.append(socket);
        win.set_child(container);

        win.default_width = 300;
        win.default_height = 300;
        win.present();
    });
    return wut.run(args);
}
```

Comment: It's really confusing, I'm using Gtk.StyleContext.add_provider_for_display() and no deprecated message appears, but it actually appears in the documentation as deprecated.

Despite this, having to add providers for each widget separately seems terrible to me.

Comment: yep totally, way more convenient than per-widget providers, but the volume of warnings is killing iteration times on large programs. I must be doing something incorrectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, I discovered the answer: It's a documentation error. Specifically in the Gtk documentation and Vala's bind.

The Gtk documentation says that the entire `Gtk.StyleContext` class is deprecated, but this is an error. Only the functions are deprecated, the static functions of the class (`Gtk.StyleContext.add_provider_for_display` and `Gtk.StyleContext.remove_provider_for_display`) and the class itself are not deprecated.

Here is an [issue](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/vala/-/issues/1429) that talks about it.

In short, the correct way is to use `Gtk.StyleContext.add_provider_for_display()`, the exceptions thrown are an error in Vala's bind, which follows the error in the Gtk documentation.

Comment: Got it thanks: Issue(s) were closed, incorrect warnings remain.

For now the temporary solution seems to be
    valac mysrc.vala --disable-warnings --pkg gtk4 ...